# Wordpress - Custom Blog Page

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like to show a static front page and custom posts page. I created 2 page templates for this.

```
page-template-home.php //commented it as Template Name: Home Template)
page-template-blog.php //commented it as Template Name: Blog Template)
```

Then created 2 wordpress pages Home and Blog, then for the home page, set page template as Home Template and for the blog page, set page template as Blog Template.

And from Settings > Reading I set

```
Front page: Home
Posts page: Blog
```

Now the Home page is perfect, but the blog page seems to load `index.php` rather than `page-template-blog.php`

Any thing that I am missing or doing wrong ??

Comment: consider move this to http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're making a little work for yourself here - I would forget custom templates and instead utilise the [template hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy) - `front-page.php` for the home page (front page), and `home.php` for the blog page.

You'll still need to have your settings as you've described in your question, but the 'control' pages are now independent of the templates that render them :)